# Show UIView on long tap on button

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, swift, uibutton

maybe someone already asked this question, but I haven't found it.

I have some buttons on my screen, and when the user taps a button (and holds it for about 2 seconds), a new UIView schould appear exactly where the user was tapping. Like a button on the iOS keyboard, if you tap (for example) the "E" button, it should show a new view containing some extra buttons.

I didn't find any solution how to do this, so please help me if you know how to fix that.

EDIT:
I've added the LongPressGestureRecognizer, but this gesture gets never fired.

Here's my code:

```
var longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "buttonLongPressed:")
    longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.5
    longPressGestureRecognizer.allowableMovement = 1

    for buttonTitle in buttonTitles{
        var button : UIButton!
        if(buttonTitle.length == 1) {
            button = createButtonWithTitle(buttonTitle)
        } else {
            button = createButtonWithImage(buttonTitle)
        }

        button.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)
    }


func buttonLongPressed(recognizer : UILongPressGestureRecognizer) -> (Void) {
    NSLog("tapped")
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Failed) {
        NSLog("failed")
    }
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
        NSLog("ended")
    }
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
        NSLog("began")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    //set gesture recognizer for long press
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressedHandler:)];
    [button addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    [gestureRecognizer release];
```

Comment: What has the "longPressedHandler:" to look like? What parameters? And how can I get the position where the user tapped?

Comment: I also want to implement the feature, when the user taps a button and swipes is fingere around, it always should active the button where the users' finger is at the moment. Because usually, if you tap a button, this button stays "active" until you release it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(action:)];
                longpress.minimumPressDuration = 0.3;
 [<button> addGestureRecognizer:longpress];

- (void)action:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

}
```

Use the above code snippet it helps you in firing an action after long press and long press time can be modified.

Comment: ok thank you! and how can I use this event when a user swipes with his finger from one button to another button?

Comment: once check with this property allowableMovement.